# www.stackoverflow.com not responding

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I have got a server not found at a few times during the last few days when trying to reach stackoverflow. It turns out that my web browser suggests www.stackoverflow.com which doesn't always work. The URL stackoverflow.com does work.

Comment: All of a sudden, I have the same issue on my work desktop. 

http://stackoverflow.com works fine, but http://www.stackoverflow.com or http://meta.stackoverflow.com does not work. 

http://blog.stackoverflow.com, oddly works as expected.

Comment: I was having the same issue last night

Comment: I didn't notice since my shortcut does not have the www, but if I enter the http://www.stackoverflow.com/ it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

There must be something wrong with your resolver configuration:

```
robert@rm:~> host www.stackoverflow.com
www.stackoverflow.com is an alias for stackoverflow.com.
stackoverflow.com has address 69.59.196.211
```